# Can I check a PDF document for images with a certain marker (alt-text / some other marker I can make in Word) and remove all images with that marker?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, pypdf

I found questions about deleting all images, but can't find anything specific to what I need.

## Background:

I'm making answer keys for a math course book. I have a Word document of the book, but don't want to update the answer key each time I update the course book (change order of questions / formatting / ...). I want to write all the answers in the course book directly, and then save as PDF both WITH and WITHOUT the answers.

For text I can do this (create new style --> write all answers with this style selected --> modify style colour to white if I don't want to print the answers). However, some questions have to be solved by drawing. I either can make these drawings again in Word, or I would insert an image (scan of the drawing on paper).

## My question:

### Mark the images that need to toggle show/don't show

So, I need a way to mark certain images with some kind of tag. I thought maybe the Alt-Text could be useful, but I can't find a way to get the Alt-Text of images in a PDF with Python. But if there is any other kind of marker/tag that I can place on the images that can be read, that's fine too.

### Print the document either with or without the images with that marker

Then, I want to have 2 PDF documents: one without those specific images (student version), and one with those images (answer key). **I don't mind if it is done in Word directly on the .docx file, or after the fact on the PDF file (preferably with Python)**

Comment: @KJ What are you talking about? I'm really struggling to see what your reply has to do with my question. I think you may have really misunderstood what I wrote.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, I do know what an Alt-Text is, I was just wondering if it was something I could use as a "hack" for what I want. As for the last part of your answer, that unfortunately won't work because the answers will be in between the text, or even be images that should cover up other images.

Comment: @KJ I think I see now why you got confused about reading the Alt-Text, and have edited a sentence in my question to this: "...but I can't find a way to **get** the Alt-Text of images in a PDF **with Python**." As for the second part, yes I understood your suggestions, but that won't work, because the answers are both in between questions and sometimes even covering up other images in the document. What you're suggesting would make the amount of work no different than if I keep the answers in a separate document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my specific problem, but have to preface it by saying it is not about the Alt-Text of the PDF file.

Thanks to a Reddit post suggesting to ask ChatGPT, because the AI actually did give me an idea about using Text Boxes in Word, which I then adapted in the following way:

**Setup**

1. Create a Style, I'll call it "AnswerTextBox"
2. Create a Text Box where you want to have a toggleable image (can be both in line or free to move)
3. Set the Text Box fill and border to "no colour"
4. Paste the image inside the Text Box
5. Apply the "AnswerTextBox" Style to the Text Box

**To toggle the images**

6. Be anywhere in the document
7. Right click the "AnswerTextBox" Style
8. Modify
9. Select "Format" and "Paragraph"
10. Set the "Line Spacing" option to "Exactly"
11. Type the lowest possible value (0.7 pt for me)
12. Select OK
13. The images disappear!
14. (To show the images again you just set the "Line Spacing" option back to "Single")